# Using Refresh[..] with TrackedSymbols

Tags: dynamic

This is a very basic question, but I don't understand the following behavior. The usage to `Refresh` reads

> represents an object whose value in a Dynamic should be refreshed at times specified by the options opts.

Although the word *times* was mentioned explicitly the examples suggest, that `Refresh` can also be used to restrict the `TrackedSymbols` in an expression inside `Dynamic`. Here is a basic example from the help, which works like a charm

```
Manipulate[
 {x, Refresh[y, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]},
 {x, 0, 1},
 {y, 0, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When you move the `y`-slider, nothing happens because the second expression containing `y` is restricted to keep only track of `x`. When you then move `x`, the `y` values jumps to it's current value.

Now, let's extend this example a bit

```
Manipulate[
 {Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}], 
  Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]},
 {x, 0, 1},
 {y, 0, 1}
]
```

What I had hoped for was, that when I move the `x`-slider, only the `x`-value in the second `{x,y}` is updated because the first `{x,y}` tracks only `y`. Equivalent for the `y`-slider. Unfortunately, all values are always updated.

Solutions to this is can be found at the end of the post, but first my question:

**Can someone explain what I have missed in the documentation of `Refresh` and how this is supposed to be used?**

Several solutions to the toy-example can be found. The most prominent one is to wrap each `Refresh` in `Dynamic`

```
Manipulate[{
  Dynamic@Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}], 
  Dynamic@Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]}, 
  {x, 0, 1}, 
  {y, 0, 1}
]
```

This goes along with the suggestion of andre's answer, when I understood him right.

Further solutions are

```
Manipulate[
 {Dynamic[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}], 
  Dynamic[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]},
 {x, 0, 1},
 {y, 0, 1}
]

DynamicModule[{},
 Column@{Dynamic[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}], 
   Dynamic[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}],
   Slider[Dynamic[x]],
   Slider[Dynamic[y]]
}]


DynamicModule[{},
 Column@{Dynamic@Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}], 
   Dynamic@Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}],
   Slider[Dynamic[x]],
   Slider[Dynamic[y]]
}]
```

This leaves the question, when I have to use `Dynamic` anyway, why does the documentation suggest `Refresh` can do this alone. I still think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think I have to explain how I look at `Dynamic` before I can speak about `Refresh`.

`Dynamic` is the basic element of dynamic updating, and the only one as far as I can tell.  Anything that behaves dynamically has `Dynamic` somewhere inside it, I believe.

If you think of an expression as a tree, then `Dynamic[code]` marks out the branch representing `code` for dynamic updating.  An update can occur only if `code` evaluates to something visible in the front end.  The whole branch will be reevaluated when an update occurs -- even the invisible parts if `code` is, say, a `CompoundExpression`.

By default, an update occurs any time one or more of the symbols in `code` changes value.  `Refresh` can be used to restrict when updating occurs through the `TrackedSymbols` option.  (It can also cause updates that depend only on time through the `UpdateInterval` option.)  `TrackedSymbols` does not make an expression depend on symbols it does not contain; rather, the dependence will be on the intersection of the symbols in `code` and in the `TrackedSymbols` list.

`Refresh` always needs a surrounding `Dynamic` for updates to occur.  `Manipulate` does this automatically, so `Refresh` by itself inside a `Manipulate` will have an effect.  See, for instance, [Advanced Manipulate Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html):

> In reading those, keep in mind that `Manipulate` simply wraps its first argument in `Dynamic` and passes the value of its `TrackedSymbols` option to a `Refresh` inside that.

See also the section on `Refresh` in [Advanced Dynamic Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#1172318352). These expand the cryptic explanation from the [manual page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Refresh.html):

> When `Refresh[expr,opts]` is evaluated inside a `Dynamic`, it gives the current value of `expr`, then specifies criteria for when the `Dynamic` should be updated.

---

As a first example, consider

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 Column[{
   {x,
    Dynamic[{x,
      Dynamic@Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}]}],
    Dynamic@Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}]},

   Slider[Dynamic[x]],
   Slider[Dynamic[y]]
   }]
 ]
```

The main expression to consider is

```
{x, 
 Dynamic[{x,
   Dynamic[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}]}], 
 Dynamic[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}]}
```

Note that two of the subexpressions look the same.  I might represent it as a tree thus:

[image: Tree diagram of the code show the dynamic sub-branches]

The frames on the branches represent `Dynamic` wrappers, and the tracked symbols are in the upper left corner.

When the slider for `x` is moved, dynamic expressions depending on `x` are reevaluated (in the kernel) and updated (in the front end).  Only the middle one is dynamic and depends on `x`.  The first `x` is never even initialized (see note* below), and it never changes.

When the slider for `y` is moved, dynamic expressions depending on `y` are reevaluated and updated.  These are the last two.  The middle one has an interior `Dynamic` that depends on `y` (only), which would seem to make the whole middle `Dynamic` depend on `y`, too; however, it is wrapped in `Dynamic` so changes to `y` only affect that branch.  (*Mathematica* will updated the smallest branch necessary.)  [Thanks to @andre for pointing out a mistake in the previous explanation.]

There is a curious difference between the middle and last expressions.  The two `Dynamic@Refresh..` expressions look identical but they do not behave the same.  When `x` is changed, the one inside the middle updates its display, but the one at the end does not.  The reason is the outer `Dynamic` in the middle depends on `x`.  It reevaluates its expression when `x` changes, including evaluating the `Dynamic@Refresh` that is a part of the expression.

(*In fact, the first `x` is never even mapped to a front end context symbol, something like `` FE`x$$14 ``.  It displays as simply `x$$`.  The other `x` in the expression are in a `Dynamic` and they get renamed to something like `` FE`x$$14 ``.  Try `DynamicModule[{x, y}, {x, Dynamic[Hold[x]]}]` and see.)

---

*Analysis of a couple of @halirutan's examples.*

A. This one

```
Manipulate[
 {x, Refresh[y, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]},
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

is equivalent to

```
Dynamic@Refresh[{x, Refresh[y, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]}, 
  TrackedSymbols :> {x, y}]
```

The main expression, `{x,Refresh[y,TrackedSymbols:>{x}]}`, depends only on `x`: `Refresh` limits the expression `y` to depend on the symbols in the tracked symbols list that occur in the expression.  So it can depend only on `x`, but no `x` appears in `y`.  Therefore the `Refresh` does not depend on any symbol and will not generate an update.  In all then, the main expression depends only on `x`.

So it is not updated when `y` changes, only when `x` changes.

B. And this one

```
Manipulate[
 {Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}],
  Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]},
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

is equivalent to

```
Dynamic@Refresh[
  {Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}],
   Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]},
  TrackedSymbols :> {x, y}]
```

Again there is only one `Dynamic`. Since only subexpressions inside a `Dynamic` are updated and like above the single `Dynamic` contains everything, then everything will be updated or nothing will be.  The first `Refresh` depends on `y` and the second on `x`; thus together, the whole depends on both `x` and `y`.  Therefore it is updated whenever `x` or `y` changes.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the text :"The middle one has an interior Dynamic that depends on y (only), which makes the whole middle Dynamic depend on y, too; so the whole middle Dynamic is updated, which causes the interior Dynamic to be evaluated, since it is part of the whole." In fact when you move y only the inner Dynamic is updated. This error may be due to a stupid typing error in my answer (yet corrected). I have tested this with the following code (see next comment)

Comment: Here is the code : `z = 0;
Dynamic[z]` -next cell-
`DynamicModule[{x, y}, Column[{
   {x,
    Dynamic[{z = z + 1; x, 
      Dynamic@Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}]}, 
     TrackedSymbols :> {x, y}],
    Dynamic@Refresh[{x, y}, TrackedSymbols :> {y}]
    },
   Slider[Dynamic[x]],
   Slider[Dynamic[y]]}
  ]]`. The idea is to increment a new variable z in the outer `Dynamic` and to observe it dynamically. I have also added `TrackedSymbols:>{x,y}` in the outer `Dynamic`. It does not change the problem and avoid auto-updating of z. If not clear, where can I put the commented code ?

Comment: @andre Yes, of course.  I just now wrote a complete explanation of how it work before I realized I had misspoken above: The `Dynamic` around the interior isolates it so that changes to `y` cause updates only to that branch of the code; the rest of the middle part is independent of `y` and is not updated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Imagine you are the front end. Once upon a time, you were told to display some `DynamicBox`

So, you need to know what it evaluates to AND the list of tracked symbols that would trigger its next update, and perhaps some upper bound on the update interval.

So you ask your friend the kernel to evaluate what is inside. Whatever symbol responsible for a transformation,  gets added to that list of tracked symbols. If in the process he runs into a `Refresh`, then it evaluates like `Identity` but while he is in the process of evaluating it, some special behaviour can be set. `Refresh` can provide a list of candidates to be tracked (they still have to be used in a transformation to be added to the list), or set "manually" the dynamic's update interval for example. Once evaluation is over, and boxed up, you display it and just sit and wait for your friend the kernel to tell you some symbol of the list has changed, or the maximum waiting time is up.

And they lived happily ever after

Moral:

- There is one tracked symbol list and one update interval for each `Dynamic`
- `Refresh` controls what gets added to those lists while the contents of the `Dynamic` are being evaluated
- `Refresh[x, TrackedSymbols:>{y}]` does nothing different than `Refresh[x, None]`
- `{x, Refresh[x, None]}` is equivalent to `{x, x}`

Comment: +1 What a nice story!  And a good summary of what's going on.

Answer (score 6):

I think that `Refresh` triggers the update of the next enclosing `Dynamic`, but `Refresh` itself is not triggerable

... and once `Dynamic` triggered, `Refresh` has no effect.

In that case the documentation should be something like : "represents an object in a Dynamic. This Dynamic should be refreshed at times specified by the options opts."

Comment: When I understand you correctly, than this goes along with what I have found while  searching for different solutions. I'm still a bit disappointed about the situation. Nevertheless +1

Comment: Are there problems with my "English" ?

Comment: Hehe, or with mine :-) I'm a bit confused about the word *fires*, because to fire an updating event a controller like `Slider` is necessary. When you watch the communication between front end and kernel, then you notice, that an expression like `Dynamic[x]` only *receives* the update events. But your point, that `Refresh` sometimes needs a surrounding `Dynamic` seems to be valid.

Comment: @haliturian I have made a very stupid typing error. "Nest" should be "Next". Otherwise, "to fire" = "to trigger" in this context. "Trigger" would have been better because less metaphoric. I'm still not clear on all this and working on the subject. Be patient.

Comment: I have seen the nest thing. Why don't you edit your answer. There is a button and you can always change/improve/update your answer!

Comment: I have edited my answer : replacement of "nest" by "next" (stupid typing error) and replacement of "to fire" by "to trigger" (more exact English)

Comment: Concerning the behavior of Dynamic and Refresh, I think that the best thing to do is to improve Michael E2 Answer (if he is interested and has time). I intend to suggest him improvements/corrections.