# Selective evaluation of blocks of code in a Manipulate

Tags: dynamic, manipulate, evaluation

Is it possible to attach certain pieces of code to certain controls in a Manipulate?  For example, consider the following Manipulate

```
Manipulate[
 data = Table[function[x], {x, -Pi*10, Pi*10, Pi/1000}];
 ListPlot[{x, data}, PlotRange -> {{start, stop}, Automatic}]
 , {function, {Sin, Cos, Tan}}
 , {start, 1, Length[data]}
 , {{stop, 300}, 1, Length[data]}
 ]
```

Generation of the data is expensive but it only needs to be done if I change function.  So, I'd like the line

```
data = Table[function[x], {x, -Pi*10, Pi*10, Pi/1000}];
```

to only run when I change the function control...i.e. I want to attach that line of code to the 'function' control.  As it stands, the data is generated when I move the plot range too which is not what I want.

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be a `Manipulate` or are you fine with a `DynamicModule`? One option for `Manipulate` is to memoize it...

Comment: DynamicModule would be fine.  I'm just interested in the general principle.  In real applications, the data is *very* expensive to compute and might be huge so memoization would be costly to say the least.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In such cases, you can get better flexibility by switching to a `DynamicModule` and building up the GUI yourself. Then, you can pull the data generating step out of the plotting dynamic, so that the latter can be manipulated freely without regenerating the data.

```
DynamicModule[{function = Sin, start, stop = 300, x = Range[-10 Pi, 10 Pi, Pi/100]},
    Dynamic@With[{data = function[x], s = Spacer@10, f = Print@10},
        Panel@Column[{
            Row[{"function", s, Control[{function, {Sin, Cos, Tan}}]}],
            Row[{"start", s, Slider[Dynamic@start, {1, Length@data}]}],
            Row[{"stop", s, Slider[Dynamic@stop, {1, Length@data}]}],
            Dynamic@ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{start, stop}, Automatic}, 
                ImageSize -> 400, Background -> White]
        }]
    ]
]
```

[image]

Note that the `f = Print@10` is there just to observe evaluation of `data`. You can check for yourself that nothing is printed when you move the sliders and prints only when the tabs are changed.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a fairly simple way to fix your `Manipulate` by applying `Dynamic` to `ListPlot`.

```
Manipulate[
 (* Beep[]; *)
 data = function @ Range[-Pi*10., Pi*10, Pi/1000];
 Dynamic @ ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{start, stop}, Automatic}],
 {function, {Sin, Cos, Tan}},
 {start, 1, Length[data]},
 {{stop, 300}, 1, Length[data]},
 {data, ControlType -> None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Uncomment `Beep[]` to hear when `data` is reevaluated.

There are several questions on this site whose answers discuss using `Dynamic` for such a purpose.  This one is more general than most: [Using Refresh[..] with TrackedSymbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21625/using-refresh-with-trackedsymbols)

Answer (score 7):

This is good reason to use the second argument of dynamics.

[image]

```
Manipulate[     
 function; (*just to allow tracking, since not explicity in the command*)     
 ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{start, stop}, Automatic}, 
  ImageSize -> 300, ImagePadding -> 30, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {"x", function}}
  ],

 Grid[
  {
   {"function", SetterBar[Dynamic[function, {function = #; 
        data = Table[function[x], {x, -Pi*10, Pi*10, Pi/10}]} &], {Sin, Cos, Tan}]
   },

   {"start", Manipulator[Dynamic[start, {start = #} &], {1, Dynamic@Length@data, 1}],
    Dynamic[start]
   },

   {"stop",Manipulator[Dynamic[stop, {stop = #} &], {300, Dynamic@Length@data, 1}], 
     Dynamic[stop]
   }       
   }],

 {{start, 1}, None},
 {{stop, 300}, None},
 {{data, Table[Sin[x], {x, -Pi*10, Pi*10, Pi/10}]}, None},
 {{function, Sin}, None},
 {{x, Symbol}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {function, start, stop}
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks Nasser. How did you record the little animation?

Comment: @WalkingRandomly one way to make animation gif from Manipulate is using `ManToGif[]` command, http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/86994  another way, is to do movie screen capture and save to animation GIF. For screen capture, on windows I use CamStudio, and to convert the AVI file from camStudio to animated gif, I use VirtualDub, all free software.