# Why doesn't Dynamic update if it only contains a Set statement?

Tags: dynamic

Consider the following toy example:

```
DynamicModule[{t = 1, v = 2},
 {Dynamic[(t = t + 1); {}, TrackedSymbols :> {v}], 
  Slider[Dynamic@v, {0, 10, 1}], Dynamic@v, Dynamic@t}
 ]
```

which gives
[image]

Why isn't the first `Dynamic` object updated? I added the empty list because I figured the problem might have been that the object is not updated if it's not displayed on the frontend, but that doesn't seem to be enough to make it work.

Comment: `TrackedSymbols` can restrict default tracked symbols but can't extend it. So you need to add `v` to `Dynamic's` first argument so it is in the default set in the first place. `Dynamic[v; t =....]`.

Comment: @Kuba ah, I didn't know that. Any way to make a dynamic statement that only updates a variable without having to print void brackets? `DynamicModule[{t = 1, v = 2}, (
  Dynamic[v; t = t + 1;, TrackedSymbols :> {v}];
  {Slider[Dynamic@v, {0, 10, 1}], Dynamic@v, Dynamic@t}
  )]` doesn't work. `DynamicModule[{t = 1, v = 2}, {
  Dynamic[v; t = t + 1; {}, TrackedSymbols :> {v}],
  {Slider[Dynamic@v, {0, 10, 1}], Dynamic@v, Dynamic@t}
  }]` works but it's ugly

Comment: You can use `Spacer[0]` instead of `{}`, or take a look at `DynamicWrapper` for a more idiomatic approach.

Comment: Could this be considered a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21625/5478? More because of the answer than the question.

Comment: @Kuba yes that essentially answers my question, thanks