# Why doesn't Dynamic update if it only contains a Set statement? [strict]

Tags: dynamic

Consider the 3 following manually entered evaluations where a `Set` statement is brought to the Front-End by `Dynamic`:

[image: Unexpected]

Obviously the `Set` statement in `Dynamic` is evaluated only once, at the beginning. Despite remaining on the screen at all times and despite manual future alteration of `t`, `t=0` does not seem to be evaluated again. According to documentation I would expect the `Set` statement to be evaluated each time `t` changes.

Why is this so? I failed to see the explanation in the neat answers [Using Refresh[..] with TrackedSymbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21625/using-refresh-with-trackedsymbols)! and advanced `Dynamic` documentation.

This is further surprising, considering that adding `t;` in the `Dynamic` expression, recovers systematic evaluation of `t=0` when `t` is altered:

[image: Expected]

Later increment: following the suggestion by Kuba in the comments about using `t[]`, here is a third case where `t[0]` apparently does not depend on `t` (like the first case) but actually updates this time.

[image]

Thank you for you help and keep on the good work.

Comment: The statement `t = 0` does not depend on the value of `t`.  The statement `t; t = 0` does, since `t` is evaluated.

Comment: Ok, it is not sufficient that `t` formally (lexically) appears in the expression to be updated by `Dynamic`. I better understand the logics now, somehow clearer than the multipage documentation, thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86804/discussion-on-question-by-steppingstone-why-doesnt-dynamic-update-if-it-only-co).

Comment: +1 -- If @Kuba & I can have an argument about the correct answer to a question, without the OP having to clarify the question at all, then the question deserves an upvote from me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following two criteria explain why `Dynamic[t = 0]` does not update and `Dynamic[t; t = 0]` updates.

Suppose we have `Dynamic[code]` where `code` is some relatively simple code depending only on a symbol `t`.  Then `code` will be update (executed) dynamic when

1. `t` is evaluated when `code` is evaluated and
2. `t` has changed its value.

There are several abstruse examples in the [chat conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86804/discussion-on-question-by-steppingstone-why-doesnt-dynamic-update-if-it-only-co), but I believe they are all explained by these criteria.

**`Dynamic[t = 0]`:** `Set` does not evaluated the LHS `t`, although it might change its value.  Since criterion 1 is not satisfied, there is no update even if condition 2 is satisfied (when `t = 1` is executed and changes the value of `t`).

**`Dynamic[t; t = 0]`:** Now `t` is evaluated before `Set`.  Since criterion 1 is satisfied, there is an update when condition 2 is satisfied (when `t = 1` is executed and changes the value of `t`).

**`Dynamic[t[] = 0]`:** `Set` does not evaluated the LHS `t[]` but the head `t` is evaluated.  Since criterion 1 is satisfied, there is an update when condition 2 is satisfied (when `t[] = 1` is executed and changes the value of `t`).

**`Dynamic[t[[1]] = 0]`:** Assuming `t` has been appropriately initialized (e.g. `t = {1}`), `Set` does not evaluated the LHS `t[[1]]` nor does it evaluate `t`. The `FullForm` of the LHS is `Part[t, 1]`, and presumably the head `Part` is evaluated.  In order to alter `t`, `Set` cannot evaluate `t` in this case.  Since criterion 1 is not satisfied, there is no update even if condition 2 is satisfied (when `t[[1]] = 1` is executed and changes the value of `t`).